# Is it possible to calculate NDVI using a landsat 8 .img file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi

I have a mosaic image with this file extension (.img) When I use image analysis in arcmap.10.4 to calculate NDVI I get values the following values

High: 3
Low : -5

NDVI values are supposed to be between -1.0 and 1.0 so this is wrong. Just wondering if it's even possible to calculate NDVI with an Erdas Imagine Image in arcmap.

Comment: The image is in DN or reflectance? Do you know image source? High and low values are often? Did you check histogram? It's posible that those values are from saturated pixels and yes, it's posible to calculate NDVI from a .img file

Comment: Hey The image has been processed for reflectance and its bee sources from the USGS site

Comment: Surface Reflectance Higher-Level Data or Level 1 (TOA reflectance)?

Comment: sorry I have no idea but when i zoom in to the map the image disappears and only appears to float about the map

Comment: When I load the bands at the start their values are appx 3000 High and - 3000 Low if that helps

Comment: You should know exactly the valid range of your image to let me help you. Are normal values from 0 to 1000? 0 to 100? 0 to 255?

Comment: It's a 16 bit unsigned image , when i load bands 4 (min = -2 and max = 1018) and band 5 (min = -3 and max = 605)

Comment: negative values generates NDVI values out of -1 to 1 range. Also, you have to stretch to 0, there isn't negative reflectance values

Comment: I think i've figured it out i've calculated NDVi and the values are high = 225 and low = 0

Comment: That's weird. You have 8 bits values in a 16 bit image. I would look deeper in data origin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64320/discussion-between-ray-and-aldo-tapia).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution through ArcMap, but you can do it easily through Mapinfo Advanced.

Just open up your file in Mapinfo and Go to Raster Tab.
After that go to operations and select Calculator tool.

In calculator tool select Red and NIR band from the input.
From Operations drop-down select NDVI. And click calculate button.
[image]

[image]

The output that you will get will have NDVI range from -1 to 1.
And it's fast.

So in the example i have a Landsat 7 img file. And i am running NDVI analysis on it.

Also please note that Mapinfo follows 0 based index for different bands. So Landsat 7 has NIR at band 4 then you will need to select 3 in calculator tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should always run it in ERDAS before you could display in ArcMap, because both of them have different formats to display and problems...

For example, if you did mosaic in ERDAS, then do the NDVI in ERDAS or otherwise if you mosaic in ERDAS and then run NDVI in ArcMap you may run into problems.

If you mosaic in ArcMap, and run NDVI, do it in NDVI in Arcmap, otherwise you will have the same problem.